# Problem installing npm calendar package on angular

Tags: angular, calendar

i have a problem when i try to install package npm on angular, i have this kind of error but i don't understand how i should do to solve it

`PS C:\Users\user\Documents\Progetti\myProject\ng-app\src\app> npm i angular-calendar npm WARN config global` --global`,` --local`are deprecated. Use`--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: ng-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@13.3.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~13.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@">=14.0.0" from angular-calendar@0.30.1
npm ERR! node_modules/angular-calendar
npm ERR!   angular-calendar@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-12-02T08_36_42_518Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\Progetti\myProject\ng-app\src\app> `

I have already done the following steps:

1. deleted "node_modules" folder
2. deleted the "package-lock.json"
3. delete cache with "npm cache clean --force"
4. called the "npm install --save" command

if i try to install the npm packet i have always the same error
where am I wrong
thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you should install with this command:

```
    npm install --save angular-calendar date-fns
```

or use

```
    ng add angular-calendar
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The errors message states that you have packages depending on both @angular/core versions ~13.3.0 and >=14.0.0. Since you can only have one version of a package, and one package can't be version 13.3.x and >= 14.x.x, it asks you to fix the issue.

Figure out packages you're installing together with their dependencies. It's hard to say from your unformatted error, but I'd assume latest version of the `angular-calendar` requires >= 14 and you're using 13.3.x.

Either download older version of `angular-calendar` that works with 13.x or upgrade your project to 14.x